# How to write SSRS Report Expression?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I converted

```
If {W40_10Q.TenureType}="Sub Lease" then
{W40_10Q.CurrentYear}*(-1)
Else
{W40_10Q.CurrentYear}
```

to  Expression

```
=IIF(Fields!TenureType.Value = Fields!Lease.Value, "Fields!CurrentYear.Value *(-1)" "Fields!CurrentYear.Value")
```

But it is giving me an error. Where I need to take TenureType, SubLease, Currentyear from "dataset1".

Comment: some of those quotes seem a bit odd and you appear to be missing a comma? =IIf(Fields!TenureType.Value = "Sub Lease", Fields!CurrentYear.Value * -1", Fields!CurrentYear.Value)

Comment: How does this takes a value from dataset1? you have not mentioned syntax for  dataset.

Comment: What is the error you get, is it an error in the expression editor or an error when you run the report?

Comment: Hey i am able to resolve it now, now can you tell me how to write expression for {@RentNow}+{@Rent1}+{@Rent2}+{@Rent3}+{@Rent4}+{@Rent5}+{@RentR}

Comment: Is it correct? =Sum(Fields!RentNow.Value,Fields!Rent1.Value) so on

Comment: Nope, you can't use SUM that way, it only SUMs one value at a time (although you can also define scope and recursion).  You would probably need to do something like =Sum(Fields!RentNow.Value) + Sum(Fields!Rent1.Value) + Sum(Fields!Rent2.Value) + ...etc...